# Returning Array value from a function

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, return

I'm having an issue returning the array value from the multiply function. I would like to know what's the best approach for this? Appreciate any help. Thanks

```
<head>
<script>

function test() {
    let list1 = [ 17, 8, 9, 5, 20 ];
    let list2 = [ 12, 4, 8, 15, 17, 5, 20, 11 ];

    // Test the multiply function by calling it two times.
    let mult1 = multiply(list1,3);
    let mult2 = multiply(list2,2);

function multiply(list,x) {            
    var myArray = [0];
    for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
      myArray[i] = list[i] * x;            
    }   
  return myArray;  
}

let output = mult1 + '<br>' + mult2;

</script>

</head>

<body>
<button type="button" click="test()">Compute</button>
<p id="output"></p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3):

First, you miss one curly brace for your **test** function.

```js
function test() {
    let list1 = [ 17, 8, 9, 5, 20 ];
    let list2 = [ 12, 4, 8, 15, 17, 5, 20, 11 ];

    // Test the multiply function by calling it two times.
    let mult1 = multiply(list1,3);
    let mult2 = multiply(list2,2);

// You miss this curly brace below
}
```

Second, you can't call mult1 and mult2 because they are declared in the function scope.

```js
/* This function creates a scope 
 * so every variable is declared in this function cannot be called outside
 */
function test() {
    let list1 = [ 17, 8, 9, 5, 20 ];
    let list2 = [ 12, 4, 8, 15, 17, 5, 20, 11 ];

    // Test the multiply function by calling it two times.
    let mult1 = multiply(list1,3);
    let mult2 = multiply(list2,2);
}

console.log(mult1, mult2) // undefined, undefined
// Uncaught ReferenceError: mult1 is not defined
let output = mult1 + '<br>' + mult2;
```

You can fix this as below

```js
function test() {
    let list1 = [ 17, 8, 9, 5, 20 ];
    let list2 = [ 12, 4, 8, 15, 17, 5, 20, 11 ];

    // Test the multiply function by calling it two times.
    let mult1 = multiply(list1,3);
    let mult2 = multiply(list2,2);
    // Return value here
    return { mult1, mult2 }
}
// Read it here
let { mult1, mult2 } = test();
let output = mult1 + '<br>' + mult2;
```

Comment: I've fixed that curly brace. The real problem is this function: It's not returning  myArray  value

function multiply(list,x) {            
    var myArray = [0];
    for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
      myArray[i] = list[i] * x;            
    }   
   return myArray;  
}

Comment: Where and how did you call multiply function?

Answer (score 2):

There are few issues in your code:

1. In the HTML, the `click` attribute should be `onclick`
2. To display the output in the `p` tag: first, you need to get the element by ID. Then, appending the value to the `innerHTML`.

```js
function test() {
  let list1 = [17, 8, 9, 5, 20];
  let list2 = [12, 4, 8, 15, 17, 5, 20, 11];

  // Test the multiply function by calling it two times.
  let mult1 = multiply(list1, 3);
  let mult2 = multiply(list2, 2);

  let output = document.getElementById("output");
  output.innerHTML = mult1 + '<br>' + mult2;

  function multiply(list, x) {
    var myArray = [0];
    for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
      myArray[i] = list[i] * x;
    }
    return myArray;
  }
}
```

```html
<head>


</head>

<body>
  <button type="button" onclick="test()">Compute</button>
  <p id="output"></p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can implement it like this:

```js
function test() {
  let list1 = [ 17, 8, 9, 5, 20 ];
  let list2 = [ 12, 4, 8, 15, 17, 5, 20, 11 ];

  const multiply = (list, x) => list.map(num => num * x);

  return [ multiply(list1, 3), multiply(list2, 2) ];
}

const [ mult1, mult2 ] = test();
const output = mult1 + '<br>' + mult2;


// Reflect the result inside your div#output element
document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = output;
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```